# Use Tensorflow/PyTorch to speed up minimisation of a custom function

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, pytorch, minimization

I do a lot of simulations, for which I often need to minimise complicated user-defined functions, for which I generally use `numpy` and `scipy.optimize.minimize()`. However, the problem with this is that I need to explicitly write down a gradient function, which can sometimes be very difficult/impossible, to find. And for large dimensional vectors, the numerical derivatives calculated by `scipy` are prohibitively expensive.

So, I am trying to switch to `Tensorflow` or `PyTorch` to take advantage both of their automatic differentiation capabilities, and to be able to exploit GPUs freely. Let me give an explicit example of a function who derivative is somewhat complicated to write down (would required a lot of chain rule), and thus seems ripe for `Tensorflow` or `PyTorch` -- calculating the dihedral angle between the two triangles formed by four points in 3d space:

```
def dihedralAngle(xyz):
## calculate dihedral angle between 4 nodes

    p1, p2, p3, p4 = 0, 1, 2, 3

    ## get unit normal vectors
    N1 = np.cross(xyz[p1]-xyz[p3] , xyz[p2]-xyz[p3])
    N2 = - np.cross(xyz[p1]-xyz[p4] , xyz[p2]-xyz[p4])
    n1, n2 = N1 / np.linalg.norm(N1), N2 / np.linalg.norm(N2) 

    angle = np.arccos(np.dot(n1, n2))

    return angle

xyz1 = np.array([[0.2       , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.198358  , 0.02557543, 0.        ],
       [0.19345897, 0.05073092, 0.        ],
       [0.18538335, 0.0750534 , 0.        ]]) # or any (4,3) ndarray

print(dihedralAngle(xyz1)) >> 3.141
```

I could easily minimise this using `scipy.optimize.minimize()`, and I should get 0. For such a small function, I don't really the need a gradient (explicit or numerical). However, if I wish to iterate over many, many nodes, and minimise some function that depends on all the dihedral angles, then the overhead is much higher?

My questions then --

1. How would I implement this minimisation problem using `TensorFlow` or `PyTorch`? Both for a single dihedral angle, and for a list of such angles (i.e. we need to account for looping over lists).
2. Also, could I just get the gradient using automatic differentiation, to plug back into `scipy.optimize.minimize()` if desired? For example, `scipy.optimize.minimize()` allows easily for bounds and constraints, something that I haven't noticed in the Tensorflow or PyToch optimisation modules.

Comment: 1) you probably need something like jax/autograd packages.  2) I haven't either

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using automatic computation of the gradient by torch and then the minimizer of scipy with a lib I wrote [autograd-minimize](https://github.com/brunorigal/autograd-minimize). The advantage over SGD is a better precision of the estimation (using second order methods). It is probably equivalent to using LBFGS from torch:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from autograd_minimize import minimize


def dihedralAngle(xyz):
## calculate dihedral angle between 4 nodes

    p1, p2, p3, p4 = 0, 1, 2, 3

    ## get unit normal vectors
    N1 = np.cross(xyz[p1]-xyz[p3] , xyz[p2]-xyz[p3])
    N2 = - np.cross(xyz[p1]-xyz[p4] , xyz[p2]-xyz[p4])
    n1, n2 = N1 / np.linalg.norm(N1), N2 / np.linalg.norm(N2) 

    angle = np.arccos(np.dot(n1, n2))

    return angle
def compute_angle(p1, p2):
    # inner_product = torch.dot(p1, p2)
    inner_product = (p1*p2).sum(-1)
    p1_norm = torch.linalg.norm(p1, axis=-1)
    p2_norm = torch.linalg.norm(p2, axis=-1)
    cos = inner_product / (p1_norm * p2_norm)
    cos = torch.clamp(cos, -0.99999, 0.99999)
    angle = torch.acos(cos)
    return angle

def compute_dihedral(v1,v2,v3,v4):
    ab = v1 - v2
    cb = v3 - v2
    db = v4 - v3
    u = torch.cross(ab, cb)
    v = torch.cross(db, cb)
    w = torch.cross(u, v)
    angle = compute_angle(u, v)
    angle = torch.where(compute_angle(cb, w) > 1, -angle, angle)

    return angle

def loss_func(v1,v2,v3,v4):
    return ((compute_dihedral(v1,v2,v3,v4)+2)**2).mean()


x0=[np.array([-17.0490,   5.9270,  21.5340]),
    np.array([-0.1608,  0.0600, -0.0371]),
    np.array([-0.2000,  0.0007, -0.0927]),
    np.array([-0.1423,  0.0197, -0.0727])]

res = minimize(loss_func, x0, backend='torch')

print(compute_dihedral(*[torch.tensor(v) for v in res.x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same thing.
Here is what I got.

```
def compute_angle(p1, p2):
    # inner_product = torch.dot(p1, p2)
    inner_product = (p1*p2).sum(-1)
    p1_norm = torch.linalg.norm(p1, axis=-1)
    p2_norm = torch.linalg.norm(p2, axis=-1)
    cos = inner_product / (p1_norm * p2_norm)
    cos = torch.clamp(cos, -0.99999, 0.99999)
    angle = torch.acos(cos)
    return angle
def compute_dihedral(v1,v2,v3,v4):
    ab = v1 - v2
    cb = v3 - v2
    db = v4 - v3
    u = torch.cross(ab, cb)
    v = torch.cross(db, cb)
    w = torch.cross(u, v)
    angle = compute_angle(u, v)
    # angle = torch.where(compute_angle(cb, w) > 0.001, -angle, angle)
    angle = torch.where(compute_angle(cb, w) > 1, -angle, angle)
#     try:
#         if compute_angle(cb, w) > 0.001:
#             angle = -angle
#     except ZeroDivisionError:
#         # dihedral=pi
#         pass
    return angle

v1 = torch.tensor([-17.0490,   5.9270,  21.5340], requires_grad=True)
v2 = torch.tensor([-0.1608,  0.0600, -0.0371], requires_grad=True)
v3 = torch.tensor([-0.2000,  0.0007, -0.0927], requires_grad=True)
v4 = torch.tensor([-0.1423,  0.0197, -0.0727], requires_grad=True)

dihedral = compute_dihedral(v1,v2,v3,v4)
target_dihedral = -2

print(dihedral)   # should print -2.6387


for i in range(100):
    dihedral = compute_dihedral(v1,v2,v3,v4)
    loss = (dihedral - target_dihedral)**2
    loss.backward()
    learning_rate = 0.001
    with torch.no_grad():
        v1 -= learning_rate * v1.grad
        v2 -= learning_rate * v2.grad
        v3 -= learning_rate * v3.grad
        v4 -= learning_rate * v4.grad

        # Manually zero the gradients after updating weights
        v1.grad = None
        v2.grad = None
        v3.grad = None
        v4.grad = None
print(compute_dihedral(v1,v2,v3,v4))   # should print -2
```

Comment: Do you ever actually perform a minimization?

Comment: Now it does I think.

Comment: Yep. Note that you could achieve an identical result using `torch.optim.SGD`, and you wouldn't have to manually handle each value's gradient.